# Electron-builder does not create latest.yml for auto updates (generic provider)

Tags: electron-builder

I'm trying to generate the auto update files to upload to a server. After signing and notarizing I expect the latest.yml file to be there but it's not. Not sure what I'm missing.  This is the package.json build section I'm using. (electron-builder version: 22.8.1)

```
"build": {
"appId": "com.myorg.myapp",
"productName": "Product name",
"copyright": "",
"afterSign": "./scripts/notarize.js",
"afterAllArtifactBuild": "./scripts/afterAllArtifactBuildHook.js",
"mac": {
  "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
  "hardenedRuntime": true,
  "gatekeeperAssess": false,
  "entitlements": "assets/entitlements.plist",
  "entitlementsInherit": "assets/entitlements.plist",
  "publish": {
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": "https://some-url/",
    "publishAutoUpdate": true,
    "channel": "latest"
  },
  "target": [
    "zip",
    "dmg"
  ]
},
"win": {
  "icon": "assets/icon.ico",
  "publish": {
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": "https://some-url/",
    "publishAutoUpdate": true,
    "channel": "latest"
  },
  "target": [
    "nsis",
    "zip"
  ]
},
"dmg": {
  "sign": true
},
"files": [
  "build/**/*",
  "node_modules/**/*",
  "system/**/*"
],
"directories": {
  "buildResources": "assets"
},
"fileAssociations": [
  {
    "ext": "diagram",
    "name": "Diagram.codes Project",
    "mimeType": "application/json",
    "role": "Editor"
  }
]
```

},

Comment: Did you found the reason for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @RahulSingh Facing the same issue at the moment, did you figure it out?

Comment: It's probably not your fault. See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/925